# How to add menu items to top navigation bar in Swift / MacOS

Tags: swift, menu

Wondering how you add menu items like these here, using Swift / MacOS:

[image]

The closest I've found is for [adding a "status icon" to the system-wide icons](http://footle.org/WeatherBar/) on the top-right in the top navigation bar. But I would like to add menu items to the top bar like the image shows.

Comment: Have you tried the demo project in the link that you are providing?  They tell you to delete the Main menu in the third paragraph of the Let's Code section.  If you do not delete that, but expand it. You can see all of the menu/submenu items from there.  It would appear that those are available in IB, just search for menu and add Menu Item/ Sub Menu Items.  Then create the outlets for those.

Comment: I am running into this which I think might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756038/appdelegateapplicationdidfinishlaunching-not-called-for-swift-4-macos-app-built

Answer (score 0):

Downloading this project fixed it: https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/working-without-a-nib-part-10.html It looks like it needs to be done in the `applicationWillFinishLaunching` method.