# AppDelegate#applicationDidFinishLaunching not called for Swift 4 MacOS app built from command line

Tags: swift, macos, command-line

So here is the full code:

**main.swift**

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate
NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  override init() {
    Swift.print("AppDelegate.init")
    super.init()
    Swift.print("AppDelegate.init2")
  }

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    Swift.print("AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching")
  }

  func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    Swift.print("AppDelegate.applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed")
  }
}
```

Then I compile it with:

```
swiftc Sources/*
./main
```

It logs:

```
AppDelegate.init
AppDelegate.init2
```

But then it doesn't log anything else, so I close it with CTRL+C. Not sure why it's not reaching the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method ever. Wondering if one knows of a fix for this, it seems like there is just one method that needs to be called somewhere, but I'm not sure.

I think this may be causing other issues such as NSMenu not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray, it was just because of the format of the methods, which were silently failing I guess.

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
  Swift.print("AppDelegate.applicationWillFinishLaunching")
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
  Swift.print("AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching")
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. If the method signature doesn’t follow the option protocol method exactly. It’s just a function which never gets called.